# ionic 2 / cordova read images from Documents directory iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2

My app downloads images from an external resource to the `Documents` directory using `FileTrasnfer`.
Now, in one of the pages of my app I'm supposed to display those images.

The paths I used for the images is the exact path they were downloaded to, 
then I don't understand why the images are not displayed, seems like there is no access to the files.

How can I access files in the Documents directory?

Anyone?

Comment: wow. no one dared to reply.  that means , no significant work is happening in ionic2.!!!

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same problem. Have you found any solution?

Comment: Does anyone find the solution?

Comment: how exactly are you displaying it? using `ionic-native/File`?